# If X and Y matches element in NumPy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do I check if there is an element in an array where both axes `[X, Y]` match `[drawx, drawy]`?

I have a **NumPy array**:

```
#format: [X, Y]
wallxy = numpy.array([[0,1],[3,2],[4,6]])
```

and **two other variables**:

```
#attached to a counter that increases value each loop
drawx = 3
drawy = 2
```

I'm using the array as a set of positions `[[0,1],[3,2],[4,6]]` and I need to test if `[drawx, drawy]` (also representing a position) is in one of the positions on both the X and Y axis etc. `drawx = 4` `drawy = 6` returns **true** `drawx = 3` `drawy = 2` returns **true** `drawx = 4` `drawy = 2` returns **false** `drawx = 2` `drawy = 1` returns **false**

Comment: [`[drawx, drawy] in wallxy` is actually doing `(wallxy == [drawx, drawy]).any()`.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30690604/2357112) It's really weird and completely useless.

Comment: What's your desired result, and what is it doing instead?  It seems to work just fine for me; `[3, 2] in wallxy` is `True` while, say, `[2, 3] in wallxy` is `False`.  Did you want it to return a list of `bool` types for each index?

Comment: This is a crude suggestion, but how about loop through each row in `wallxy` and then use `numpy.array_equal([drawx, drawy], [row])` to determine if your pair exists in the array? You're wanting to check _pair_ or _row_ equality, i.e. both elements in, and shape of the pair/row are a match e.g. [0,1] == [0,1] = True (both shape and elements match), [0,1] == [1,0] = False and [0,1] == [0,1,2] = False.

Comment: Or this might be what you want.  Use `wallxy.flatten()` first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625351/check-if-two-items-are-in-a-list-in-a-particular-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` will broadcast the comparison, so

```
wallxy = numpy.array([[0, 1],[3, 2][4, 6]])
z0 = numpy.array([3,2])
z1 = numpy.array([2,3])

(z0==wallxy).all(1).any()  # True
(z1==wallxy).all(1).any()  # False
```

Which is, I think, what you're looking for.

Printing out the intermediate steps will be useful to understanding and working out similar tasks:

```
z0 == wallxy     # checks which elements match
#  array([[False, False],
#         [ True,  True],
#         [False, False]], dtype=bool)

(z0==wallxy).all(1)   # checks whether all elements of axis 1 match
#  array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

(z0==wallxy).all(1).any()   # checks whether any axis 1 matches z0
#  True
```

If instead you used `z0 = numpy.array([2,3])`, then everything would be `False`.

Comment: I actually wanted to check if there is an element in the array where both axis match `drawx` and `drawy`... (I apologize my original question didn't communicate that very clearly) Thanks

Comment: @Pineapples: I guess I don't understand.  To get more specific.  Do you care about the order?  Does just one need to match or both?  Do you care about whether it's a row or column?  Do you just want one of the two to match anywhere in the array?  The most helpful would be to give examples of things you want to match and things you don't.

Comment: I'm using the array as a set of positions [[0,1],[3,2],[4,6]] and I need to test if drawx and drawy (also representing a position) is in one of the  positions on both the X and Y axis etc. 
`drawx = 4 drawy = 6` **returns true**
`drawx = 3 drawy = 2` **returns true**
`drawx = 4 drawy = 2` **returns false**
`drawx = 2 drawy = 1` **returns false**

Comment: @Pineapples: Yes, if I understand you correctly, that's what my answer does.  I've re-organized it a bit to make that more prominent.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your answer. Your method worked great:`z0 = numpy.array([drawx, drawy])
            if (z0==wallxy).all(1).any():` I was just missing `.any()` on the end of the line. Once again thanks, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

numpy doesn't have but list does

```
[3,2] in wallxy.tolist()
True
```