# giving the shortest path a different color than the rest in a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, networkx

i'm trying to give the shortest path a diffrent color than the rest of the edges but it doent work as all the edges come out with the same color

```
color_list = []
for i in G.edges():
    if i in shortestpath:  # if edges is the shortest path color with red
        color_list.append("red")
    else:  # other wise color green 
        color_list.append("Green")
print('c_list',color_list)
print(shortestpath)
#output:(3, 0, 1)
print(G.edges)
#output:[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]

weight=nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=weight)
nx.draw(G,pos,with_labels=weight)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edge_color=color_list)
plt.show()
```

so my desired output is the path (3,0,1) to be colored differently like this :
[image]

Comment: color_list_list.append("Green") -> color_list.append("Green")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already know the shortest path you can simply change the color of those edges by using the `edgelist` attribute of `nx.draw_networkx_edges`.

First, you turn your `shortest_path` tuple into a list of edges(list of tuples).

```
shortestpath = (3, 0, 1)
sp = []
for i in range(0,len(shortestpath)-1):
    sp.append((shortestpath[i],shortestpath[i+1]))
# sp = [(3, 0), (0, 1)]
```

Then paint the edges composing the shortest path in red:

```
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=weight)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=weight)
# painting every edge green
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edge_color="green")
# painting specific edges red
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=sp, edge_color="r")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is this statements:

```
if i in shortestpath
```

Here `i` can be a tuple, say `(0,1)` and you are trying to search it in `(1, 0, 3)` which will return false.

You basically need to check

1. That `0` and `1` both exist in shortest path
2. Both occur adjacent to each other

Here is the code

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge(0, 1, weight=10)
G.add_edge(2, 1, weight=5)
G.add_edge(3, 2, weight=25)
G.add_edge(0, 3, weight=3)
G.add_edge(4, 3, weight=8)

shortestpath = nx.shortest_path(G, source=1, target=3, weight='weight')

color_list = []
for u, v in G.edges():
    # Check for both cases, i.e. (0, 1) and (1, 0) exist in shortest path
    # Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8625376/8160718
    if any([u,v] == shortestpath[i:i+2] for i in range(len(shortestpath) - 1)):  
        color_list.append("red")
    elif any([v,u] == shortestpath[i:i+2] for i in range(len(shortestpath) - 1)):
        color_list.append("red")
    else:  # other wise color green 
        color_list.append("green")
print('c_list',color_list)
print(shortestpath)
#output:(3, 0, 1)
print(G.edges)
#output:[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]

weight=nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
pos=nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=weight)
nx.draw(G,pos,with_labels=weight)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edge_color=color_list)
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8625376/8160718) for more information about how the pair of elements are checked for membership and adjacency at the same time.

Here is a [Google Colab Notebook with the working code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Vz3W8QdjnTjk59E_dU7L-94W4wQuaeUT?usp=sharing).

Reference:

- [Check if two items are in a list in particular order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625351/check-if-two-items-are-in-a-list-in-a-particular-order)
- [NetworkX Shortest Path](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path)