# Check if rows in an array contain specific sequence of values and add corresponding values to another array

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array, iteration

I'm having some trouble with writing up a code that will go through an array containing rows of 5-bit strings, and depending on the sequence of the bits for it to add a corresponding 4-bit string into an empty array. The array I'm working with is:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],..,[0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

I am trying to write a loop that will go through this array (and future ones) that will do this for me but I am stuck on how I can get my code to read through each row.

A portion of the code I have currently, with 'fb' as the data array, is:

```
array = []
for i in range(len(fb)):
    if any([1, 1, 1, 1, 1] == fb[i]):
        array.append([9, 9, 9, 9])
    elif any([0, 0, 1, 0, 0] == fb[i]):
        array.append([1, 0, 1, 0])
    elif any([0, 1, 0, 1, 1] == fb[i]) & (fb[i-1, 5] == 0):
        array.append([0, 1, 1, 0])
    elif any([0, 1, 0, 1, 1] == fb[i]) & (fb[i-1, 5] == 1):
        array.append([0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Some have a second conditional that looks at the last element of the previous row. What then should happen is that I should get a new array that looks like the following:

```
[[9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0],...]
```

But the problem I have been getting has been:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I tried applying the any() to it (kinda like this: [Check if two items are in a list, in a particular order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625351/check-if-two-items-are-in-a-list-in-a-particular-order)), but the issue is that I don't know how to have it return an index. I also referred to this page: [Find a value in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/find-a-value-in-a-list) and some other ones to see if I could find an answer. I know there are other problems with what I have but I'm not sure what they are as I can't even get past the first conditional. I am still learning the ropes so I do apologize in advance for any silly things I may have done.

Comment: better show your code with `any()` or `all()`

Comment: do you use `pandas` or `numpy`? Normally it should use `and` instead of `&` because `&` is for `Bitwise operators`. And normal list can use index `[i-1, 5]`

Comment: better create minimal working code with small example data - so we could simply copy and run it.

Comment: @furas Sorry I left out the any() from the code. I've edited the question to show what I've tried with it. And I use `numpy` for this. I will change out the `&`

Comment: if you use `numpy` then `&` should be OK.

Comment: @furas It seems I have figured out an answer to this problem. I apologize for inconveniencing you. Your comment on using `and` instead of `&` was one of the answers

Comment: you could write solution as answer below - it can help other people. Later you can mark your answer as accepted, and you can upvote your answer.

Comment: @furas Will do. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was simple and I had overlooked it. The first change was using `and` instead of `&` as @furas mentioned in the comments. This was because I wasn't actually working with `numpy` arrays but rather regular `python` lists. The second change was to cut out the use of `any()` all-together. The third change was to not use `fb[i-1, 5]` but rather `fb[i-1][4]` (I also used the wrong index number). The new code now looks as follows:

```
array = []
for i in range(len(fb)):
    if fb[i] == [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]:
        array.append([9, 9, 9, 9])
    elif fb[i] == [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]:
        array.append([8, 8, 8, 8])
    elif (fb[i] == [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]):
        array.append([1, 0, 1, 0])
    elif (fb[i] == [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]) and (fb[i-1][4] == 0):
        array.append([0, 0, 0, 0])
    elif (fb[i] == [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]) and (fb[i-1][4] == 1):
        array.append([0, 1, 1, 0])
```

Where a small sample of `fb` is:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Printing the newly filled array yields what I was expecting initially:

```
[[9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 0, 1, 0], [9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 0, 1, 0]]
```